# System-wide packages break when I install conda

Tags: python, qt, pip, virtualenv, conda

I need to use Qt4 as I am building a GUI (the person before me chose this as only it is compatible with other packages).  I am trying to install fast.ai in another environment using conda(the other methods are not working easily for fastai install, and conda is very easy).  Every time I install conda, the package of qt4 breaks. Qt4 is installed using sudo apt-get install python-qt4.  It is the only one I have found to work with my system.  I am using ubuntu 16.04.  I have been doing this for days if not weeks.  I think a version of qt gets installed with conda system wide or something so this is causing a conflict.

So my question is, how to use qt4 (which I can only install system wide), and conda, which seems to install another version of qt system wide.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Although your question is about programming tools, you might be better off asking it elsewhere, e.g. on askubuntu.com. It seems that your question is more specific to Linux / Ubuntu than to programming.

Comment: oh ok thank you. I actually just solved it

Comment: Feel free to post an answer showing your solution!